# Create chronology column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe characterized by two essential columns: *name* and *timestamp*.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['tom','tom','tom','bert','bert','sam'], \
                   'timestamp':[15,13,14,23,22,14]})
```

I would like to create a third column *chronology* that checks the *timestamp* for each *name* and gives me the chronological order per *name* such that the final product looks like this:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'name':['tom','tom','tom','bert','bert','sam'], \
                         'timestamp':[15,13,14,23,22,14], \
                         'chronology':[3,2,1,2,1,1]})
```

I understand that I can go `df = df.sort_values(['name', 'timestamp'])` but how do I create the *chronology* column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `groupby().cumcount()` if the timestamps are not likely repeated:

```
df['chronology']=  df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby('name').cumcount().add(1)
```

or `groupby().rank()`:

```
df['chronology'] = df.groupby('name')['timestamp'].rank().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   name  timestamp  chronology
0   tom         15           3
1   tom         13           1
2   tom         14           2
3  bert         23           2
4  bert         22           1
5   sam         14           1
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [GroupBy.rank()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html), does exactly what you need. From the documentation:

> *GroupBy.rank(method='average', ascending=True, na_option='keep', pct=False, axis=0)*
>
> **Provide the rank of values within each group.**

Try this code:

```
df['chronology'] = df.groupby(by=['name']).timestamp.rank().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   name  timestamp  chronology
   tom         15           3
   tom         13           1
   tom         14           2
  bert         23           2
  bert         22           1
   sam         14           1
```